# How to change Bower package URLs?

Tags: yeoman, bower

I'm using `Yeoman` for an application. It uses the `Bower` package manager. All the URLs Bower gets from the server https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages are Git read-only URLs of the form `git://github.com/components/jquery.git`.

The problem is that these URLs don't work inside my institute. Probably the port is blocked.

I tried to change the URLs in `lib/core/package.js` of Bower to `HTTPS` before discovering that the URLs are fetched from the server.

So is there any way to make `Bower` work over Github's read-only `HTTPS` URLs and not `GIT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make git substitute `git://` with `https://`:

[git:// protocol blocked by company, how can I get around that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that/)