# git is blocked, how to install npm modules

Tags: windows, node.js, github, proxy, npm

We are connected through a proxy and here, **git is blocked ( not the website but on git//: )** we tried with egit, "git on windows", with and without proxy but not a single clone to local happened.

Now the problem is to install npm modules, I tried by downloading modules(zip) from git website (over web) and tried the local install, which worked but the problem here is  huge  number of dependencies, **it is not easy to pull modules one by one to fill dependencies (and inner dependencies)**.

So how to solve this problem, I feel there can be three ways to find solution:

- Allowing git tunneling through firewall (i have no friends in n/w team ).
- Suggest me some way to pull modules with dependencies over http:// (and not git://)  when doing npm install.
- Download from git website modules + full dependencies, in single shot.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to GitHub via https? git//: is blocked for us too but we are able to connect via https. The docs for [npm install](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) also give this as an option.

Comment: @penfold SSH is a good alternative too

Comment: Does your proxy require authentication?

Answer (score 64):

Copied from this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729634/1095114

---

If this is an issue with your firewall blocking the git: protocol port (9418), then you should make a more persistent change so you don't have to remember to issue commands suggested by other posts for every git repo. This also just works for submodules that might be using the `git://` protocol too.

Simply issue the following command:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

This simply adds the following two lines to ~/.gitconfig:

`[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://`

Now, as if by magic, all git commands will perform a substitution of `git://` to `https://`

Comment: I've also had issues where my gitconfig file wasn't being picked up because my home directory was mounted. Running 'git config --list --show-origin' in git v2.8 and above helped me find all the config files and make sure they had the same variables set.

Answer (score 1):

Npm and git do not use your Windows proxy settings.

You can configure them with:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@server.url:port
```

Also see https://superuser.com/questions/347476/how-to-install-npm-behind-authentication-proxy-on-windows

---

If you can't get your proxy working you can run `npm install` on a machine that has a direct internet connection (e.g. a server in the dmz, at your hosting provider, in the cloud, etc.) and then copy the `node_modules` folder to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The git proxy setting worked for me for cloning repos from github.
But, when installing/updating a npm module that uses a git url, I am still getting the timeout error. The workaround for me was to set the proxy manually in the `.git/config` file for the repo.

```
[http]
    proxy = http://proxy.company.com:8888
```

But wait, there is more: this worked for some git url but not for other. The second and final workaround was to make sure the git proxy is set in both user config files, since my PC had a shared network user home on I drive:

```
I:\.gitconfig
C:\Users\<userid>\.gitconfig
```

Credits to [this comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5257#issuecomment-60441477).