# node js npm install of github packages failing

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, github, npm

currently trying to install node js modules, some of them have installed fine but those that require gihub say npm ERR! fetch failed, such as 
npm install socket.io  gives

> npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/0f36d0b5ebc03d85f860d42a64ae9791e1daa433.tar.gz
>
> ws@0.4.31 install /home/robert/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
>
> make: Entering directory `/home/robert/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'
>    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
>    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
>    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
>    COPY Release/bufferutil.node
>    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
>    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
>    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
>    COPY Release/validation.node
>   make: Leaving directory`/home/robert/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'

and i have run npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
and npm config set strict-ssl false

is it possible to install npm updates from zip files? as i can access the failed github urls through firefox and in that way can download them.

I am running behind a proxy but have added it to the npm config file and the apt.conf file so i can apt-get properly or git clone fine, any ideas?
im running ubuntu server, 14.04 fully updated

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/installing-from-npm-fails

Comment: this helped me with a similar issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4529#issuecomment-36353975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks like a problem with your proxy, and how he handel the github access.
Pleas use the search function of this site and [google](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=npm%20github%20proxy&gws_rd=ssl), you'll find many related question.

I think this question may help you: 
[git is blocked, how to install npm modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903275/git-is-blocked-how-to-install-npm-modulesssible)

P.S. https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=npm+github+proxy&gws_rd=ssl