# Force bundle install to use https:// instead of git:// for GitHub-based gems

Tags: ruby, github, bundler

I am trying to build a rails project and because the host I am working on doesn't have access to the Internet for the the git:// protocol (port 9418) I get errors like

```
Fetching git://github.com/pivotal/jasmine.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=Connection refused
```

when running `bundle install`.

The relevant line in the GemFile doesn't specify git:// as a protocol, it just points to GitHub as the source for the gem

```
gem 'jasmine', :github => 'pivotal/jasmine-gem'
```

What do I have to do to make bundler to use https:// rather than git:// for pulling gems from GitHub?

Edit:

Is there a way other than editing every affected line in the GemFile? I'd prefer to avoid any merging issues down the line if the project's GemFile is updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git:// protocol blocked by company, how can I get around that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Git provides URL rewriting functionality using the url..insteadOf configuration option.

So to make all connections to github.com use https:// rather than git://

```
git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf git://github.com
```

The `--global` switch sets the config option for all git operations by the current user, so there are times where it may be too intrusive. But it does avoid changing the git config in the current project.

Comment: excellent answer! I didn't want to have change up every line in the Gemfile just to get things running on one particular customer site

Comment: @sam-kah-chiin answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41382363/1712589) is much better for this, since the question os about _ruby bundler_ and not git as a whole.

Comment: This was super useful for forcing `bundle install` to use the temporary SSH key I'd generated, just for use from w/in a test container, in an env where it was a hassle to get the `gh` binary for authing PATs. Ended up running `git config --global url."git://github.com".insteadOf https://github.com`  Had initially tried running `bundle config github.https false` but that had no effect.

Comment: Best answer for old versions of bundler where the `github.https` config is not yet available.

Answer (score 73):

Use `bundle config github.https true`

Comment: Best answer for this!! Thank you

Comment: Agreed. Much better than the accepted answer, since the question is _ruby bundler_ related, not git as a whole.

Comment: This change could mess up your production deployment if you don't have the same settings there.

Comment: Does not seem to have any effect in alpine docker container.

Answer (score 38):

You can do:

```
gem 'jasmine', git: 'https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem.git'
```

Comment: I just need to do it in a single place, and don't want it sneaked away in a per-server config, so this was right for me.

Answer (score 15):

If you want this just for all the gems in one Gemfile you can add these lines at the top of the file:

```rb
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
```

Alternatively you can use `bundle config github.https true`. But this affects only your current environment.

[This won't be necessary anymore with Bundler 2.0.](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/dsl.rb#L253)

Comment: Note that this option requires bundler 1.13.2+.

Comment: **DON'T DO** `bundle config github.https true` if your production environment lives on heroku!

Comment: @MichaelJohnston why not?

Comment: You can add some like this for your future self.  `Bundler.ui.warn('You are using Bundler 2.0 or greater, you don\'t need this hack any more') if Bundler.bundler_major_version > 1`

Comment: Rails 6 new includes this oneliner into Gemfile: `git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }`

Comment: @GabeKopley setting this value to true exposes your application directories to recursive search by an attacker. AVOID THIS SETTING OR LOSE YOUR DATA. I've seen this happen on Heroku.

Answer (score 10):

if you're deploying to heroku, you can just add `BUNDLE_GITHUB__HTTPS` (note the double underscore) as an environment variable and set it to `true` (in your heroku app's dashboard under the `Settings` tab in the `Config Vars` section). this will switch the protocol from `git://` to `https://` for all such requests.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to put a complete Git URL in your Gemfile. For example:

```
gem 'jasmine', :git => 'https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

If a solution that requires a special obscure setting to be performed on every installation you make for just a teeny weeny bit of syntactic sugar isn't a solution.

That's why I'm proposing this as an answer:

just use `:https` & report a security bug with bundler that the unencrypted protocol is default.