# Running "bundle install" changes "git://" to "https://" in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, git, bundler

When I run `bundle install`, the URLs in `Gemfile.lock` that begin with `remote: git://github.com` change to `remote: https://github.com`. Because I'm working on a project with other people, I can't commit these changes. How do I force Bundler to use the `git` protocol?

Other people seem to have the opposite problem and want to use `https` instead of `git`. I tried using the following command, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260689/force-bundle-install-to-use-https-instead-of-git-for-github-based-gems), but to no avail:

```
git config --global url."git://github.com".insteadOf https://github.com
```

I'm using Bundler 1.7.0 and RVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to Bundler 1.7.2 seems to solve the problem.