# Switch from git source protocol to encrypted https

Tags: git, macos, rubygems, bundler

per this [github issue conversation](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4978) and this [answer to a relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21265977/5225057) I have executed both of the following commands:

```
$ bundle config --global github.https true
$ git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf git://github.com
```

but when I use `bundle install` I am still getting the following warning message re: gits unencrypted protocol:

```
The git source uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption.
Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`,
or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
```

for both:
`git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git`
`git://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.git`

For what it is worth:
Bundler version 1.13.6
git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)
(note: git was installed through Xcode [with developers tools](https://superuser.com/a/1009364/630402))
Also, before I entered these commands I was getting four warnings related to other gems. After entering the commands, I still get warings for these two. I've looked at the README.md files for both "[capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md)" and "[shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/README.md)" and found nothing indicating a solution or cause of this issue.
Lastly, `bundle install` reports:

```
Using shoulda-matchers 3.0.1 from git://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.git (at master@db67d27)  
Using capybara 2.6.0.dev from git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git (at master@e6886de)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turned out to be the ~/project/Gemfile specified the github source:

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.git'
  gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
end
```

Removing the `, :git => 'PATH'` gets me a secure https protocol install of the lastest gems. Added bonus: the gems also now show up when I `gem list`... FWIW: this isn't a project I wrote from scratch, I'm just helping someone out with theirs, but now I know!