# Unable to start ember-cli project because of git error

Tags: git, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

When I try to execute `ember new myproject` I get the following:

```
[ ... snip ...]
  create vendor/.gitkeep
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git", exit code of #128
Error: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git"
 exit code of #128
    at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/util/createError.js:4:15)
    [ ... snip ...]
```

So I tried to execute the failing command:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Operation timed out
```

The `git://github.com` syntax was new to me, so I tried a version with the more familiar `git@github.com:`:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.com:stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git                                                                                        
3a6dc87e29efc9de4bc42b6f9afedabb000bcc89        refs/heads/master
be13fa4a45abff2c9fcfc82497668ed2a925a856        refs/tags/0.0.1
3a6dc87e29efc9de4bc42b6f9afedabb000bcc89        refs/tags/v0.0.2
$
```

Can anyone help me diagnose this issue? I'd be happy with a `git` solution`or an`ember` workaround.

**Edit:**

I have tried:

```
$ ember new myproject --skip-git
```

with the same result. I've also tried

```
$ ember new myproject --skip-bower
```

which seems to compete successfully, but then give an error on `$ ember serve`, complaining about the lack of bower components.

If I then try:

```
$ bower install
```

Then I get the same `git://` problem. So I guess this is really a bower/git problem. Still appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tends to be issue with firewalls. Verify your firewall will let you through to the `git://` domain. When I run the command I get

```
$ git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git
3a6dc87e29efc9de4bc42b6f9afedabb000bcc89        refs/heads/master
be13fa4a45abff2c9fcfc82497668ed2a925a856        refs/tags/0.0.1
3a6dc87e29efc9de4bc42b6f9afedabb000bcc89        refs/tags/v0.0.2
```

Comment: I guess you could say that I've verified that I can't get through to git://. The question is: what to do about it?

Comment: This is generally a firewall issue. If you are within an office that has one you may need to have that opened up. This comes from ember using dependencies from github directly in the package.json

Comment: You may be able to fix by this comment: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/773#issuecomment-43570471

Comment: Good suggestion. I exited my companies VPN, and it works now. This is a personal project, I had entered the VPN out of habit, so that's a good enough solution for me, though the issue you link to looks like a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by explicitly adding empty proxy settings to `.bowerrc`

```
$ ember new myproject --skip-bower
```

Then I edited the `.bowerrc` inside the project to look like this:

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components",
  "analytics": false,
  "proxy":"",
  "https-proxy":""
}
```

And finally did a

```
$ bower install
```

which worked fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
[git:// protocol blocked by company, how can I get around that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that/10729634#10729634)

So, to answer your question:

```
 $ git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git
 ...Connection timed out
 $ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
 $ git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git
2ac2abfa69f9ea682a7461fd6c46a96a56c276fd    refs/heads/master
be13fa4a45abff2c9fcfc82497668ed2a925a856    refs/tags/0.0.1
3a6dc87e29efc9de4bc42b6f9afedabb000bcc89    refs/tags/v0.0.2
```

One might argue that opening outgoing connections to port TCP 9148 would be the better solution, but this is SO. Not that rogue nation known as ServerFault

(I kid: https://serverfault.com/questions/189070/what-firewall-ports-need-to-be-open-to-allow-access-to-external-git-repositories )

Comment: thanks for asking.  My work computer will now deal with 'git://' addresses without opening port TCP 9418

Answer (score -1):

You use the `--skip-git` argument if you have problems with, and take care of versioning later by hand.

See also: `$ ember help new`

Comment: `--skip-git` didn't change anything, looks like it simply prevents ember from creating a local git repo.