# I tried using git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git:// to clone through a firewall,but its not working

Tags: git

I was trying to clone from the rtems repository

```
git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder.git
```

The institute connection has a firewall,so I got a connection timed out error how many ever times i tried.So i reffered

[git:// protocol blocked by company, how can I get around that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that)

and I diagnosed the problem using

```
curl http://github.com:9418
```

and i got this

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 9418: Connection timed out
```

which according to the post proves that my firewall is causing the problem,so i followed the post further and did this

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
```

and i retyped

```
git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder.git
```

but this did not work for me and i get the message

```
Cloning into 'rtems-source-builder'...
fatal: https://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I don't understand this as .git changes into /info/refs...how is this happening?

Please can someone help me clone the repository.

I am a newbie to linux and git,so it would be helpful if you can be detailed in answering...thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to clone you can use http instead.

`git` protocol is using ssh and it might be blocked as you just saw.

Another thing to try is to add ssh key under your git account if you can and then try again to clone.

Comment: Yeah I tried using http....git clone http://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder.git
But i still get the error

Comment: Verify that you repository support HTTP. The git admin can block any protocol he wishes.

Comment: And I tried adding an ssh key also...following guidelines from https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/....but i get this how many ever times i try to connect though ssh    .....ssh -T git@github.com    ......ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out....

Comment: how do we check if my repository supports http or not

Comment: Looks like your company block those ports. You will need to contact your IT department to check it out. its purely network configuration

Comment: http is usually for read only. open your web GUI for the GIT server and checkout the clone url there. you should have all the supported protocols

Comment: I checked it supports http...but i still get the error message......is it possible for me to clone through the firewall?

Comment: You should. contact your IT department, its pure network issues, nothing to do with GIT.