# npm install error: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: node.js, git, proxy, npm, polymer

I tried running `npm install -g polymer-cli` but it is giving me an error every time I run it.

NPM is running behind corporate proxy which is configured both for git and npm. I had no problems installing bower or gulp and I have no problem using git to clone repositories.

I have tried this with no result: 
`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` from here
 [Stack Overflow - git:// protocol blocked by company, how can I get around that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that)

This is part of the output:

```
31725 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
31726 error argv "C:\\Users\\user\Documents\\Tools\\node-v6.3.1-win-x64\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Tools\\node-v6.3.1-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "polymer-cli"
31727 error node v6.3.1
31728 error npm  v3.10.5
31729 error code 128
31730 error Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\userAppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:polymerelements/test-fixture.git C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-polymerelements-test-fixture-git-8142662e
31730 error ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
31730 error fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
31730 error
31730 error Please make sure you have the correct access rights
31730 error and the repository exists.
```

Comment: I had this error when using quotes for the package name: `npm install -g '@angular/cli'` instead of `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command as admin(open cmd and run as admin) or in linux as sudo. In my case, it solves the problem.

Comment: I don't have admin privileges, so it is problematic. And it is windows 7 x64 Enterprise machine.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with privileges. For running this you have to run the cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `id_rsa` file is in the folder `c:\users\$username\.ssh`

Configure the *ssh-agent* program to use your SSH key:
Open the console and run `start-ssh-agent`. It will find your `id_rsa` and prompt you for the `passphrase`:

```
start-ssh-agent
Removing old ssh-agent sockets
Starting ssh-agent:  done
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /c/Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Then try to run `npm install` again.

---

**Note:** It's also might be possible that the *ssh-agent* is already running:

```
start-ssh-agent
Found ssh-agent at 402860
Found ssh-agent socket at /tmp/ssh-YT2trepckpeN/agent.431360
```

In this case use ssh-add It will find your `id_rsa` and prompt you for the passphrase:

```
ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /c/Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Comment: start-ssh-agent is unrecognised for me, `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` works