# Stuck at npm install at fechMetadata checking installable status

Tags: node.js, angular, installation

Suddently I can't install angular
I get stuck at the npm install command
"npm install -g @angular/cli"
It stays forever on  this "checking installable status".

my node version is 8.11.3 (yes I already tried to uninstall node and double checked to see it was really uninstalled) this was the version I had before and was working fine
my npm -v gives 5.6.0

then I run the angular command to install angular and it seems to freezing or very very very slow....

Comment: Did you try clearing your npm cache? `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: yes I did, I am reaching the conclusion this happened right after I installed git for windows  so this is related to git and the cmd

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this?

Comment: Waiting a few more minutes worked for me

Comment: @NicolaiWeitkemper can you tell me how long you waited ?

Comment: @ibra Sorry, I don't remember. But surely less than an hour...

Comment: How did you fix this , I couldnt find any solution :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install gets stuck at fetchMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433130/npm-install-gets-stuck-at-fetchmetadata)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**npm install -g @angular/cli --verbose**

After running this command I realized npm was having problems with the connection with registry.npmjs.org

To solve this:

1. **npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"**
2. **npm set maxsockets 3**

Viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433130/npm-install-gets-stuck-at-fetchmetadata)

Comment: This worked for me.  Checking installable status was hanging the install when trying to create a new react app: npx create-react-app react_test

Comment: npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org", solved the issue for me

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had to **wait for a few minutes** and npm finally installed by package.
Also I suggest to use **--verbose** flag to see what's actually is going.

Comment: I had to wait about 3 minutes on my macbook pro.  Was not expecting that, but it eventually got over it.

Answer (score 4):

To anyone still experiencing this, I spent days searching for a solution, it ended up being easier and more effective to just remove all traces of nvm (and its node) from my machine and reinstall. Everything started working smooth again after the reinstall

I did:

```sh
brew uninstall nvm
rm -rf $NVM_DIR ~/.nvm ~/.npm ~/.bower

# remove nvm entries from my .bash_profile|.bashrc then
# installed nvm from nvm's install script

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh | bash

# add to bash_profile

cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
EOF

source ~/.bash_profile
nvm install --lts
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`npm install -g --no-optional pm2`
This will ignore all the dependencies specified in the `package.json` file (if present).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try `npm install --g --no-optional pm2`

[Check this out for reference](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2916)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify your proxy server in the global Git configuration, like this:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://your-proxy-server:port
git config --global https.proxy http://your-proxy-server:port
```

And since you mentioned you're using Git for Windows, best to put this into the system wide configuration, too (repeat these commands with `--system` instead of `--global`).

Theoretically, the global config should take precedence over the system config, but sometimes when using npm install on Windows, the global config seems to be ignored or not found. I suspect this can happen when there are conflicting settings in the `USERPROFILE` and `HOMESHARE` env vars, in which case Git may be confused and look in different places depending on how it is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have a custom registry set up in your global `.npmrc`. That was the problem in my case: my company uses a custom registry which falls back to the NPM registry. It is not a problem for work projects, because all the required packages are already present there, but I didn't realize this was affecting a new project whose packages were not included in the mirror registry and looking them all up must have been the cause of the slowdown.

I solved it by resetting the registry config to the NPM registry in an `.npmrc` for that specific project:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue is that the package I was trying to install had this in its `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "mobx-utils": "github:Venryx/mobx-utils#5.5.2_VPatch2"
}
```

Normally that works fine, but apparently today, NPM decided to hang on the call to retrieve the library contents from the GitHub repo.

I used [Process Hacker 2](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker) to investigate what exact command was hanging, and it was the following:

```
git.exe ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/Venryx/mobx-utils.git
```

In my case, I worked around the issue by just manually installing the subdependencies (and copy-pasting the mobx-utils library itself), but this is of course not ideal.

**UPDATE**: The issue is that I was running an outdated version of Git for Windows. Once I updated it to the latest version (v2.28.0), the issue was resolved. (ie. installing based on github urls/branches started working just fine again)

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe there is a service outage as in my case. Recommending to first check the status page, where you get the info, if everything is working as it should be: https://status.npmjs.org/

If you see something like this, you know, you will have to wait for a while:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

for those with the same problem try

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```