# Create new application in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I need to your help about creation new application in react js .
When I run line commande `create-react-app myapp`
the creation can't finhish and stop  at

```
fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule spdx-exceptions@2.2.0 checking installable status
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433130/npm-install-gets-stuck-at-fetchmetadata

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it, run this command in the terminal :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: I did it but not new always same issues