# npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react-is (over 30000ms)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install, npm-scripts

When I want to create a react app I'm encountering the following error:

> ```
> npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react-is (over 30000ms)
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-23T02_54_45_865Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.
>   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json
> Deleting app2/ from C:\Users\info
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 67):

Sounds like you have a slow connection. Try increasing the timeout from 30s to 60s by adding this to your `.npmrc` file:

```
timeout=60000
```

You could also try adding

```
prefer-offline=true
```

if you are trying to save bandwidth or have a slow connection

Note: if you don't have an `.npmrc` file setup yet, you can create one here

- for Windows: `C:\Users\{username}\.npmrc`
- for Mac/Linux `~/.npmrc`

Or you can create one in the same directory as your project's `package.json` file.

Comment: Adding more to your answer, .npmrc file could be found at this path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Comment: increasing timeout fixed my issue.. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I also needed to restart my computer for the change to take effect.

Comment: i don't have an slow connection and i'm facing the same issue

Comment: @FernandoTorres you might not have a slow connection, but maybe the server you are downloading the packages from is slow

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, increasing the timeout resolved my issue as well. I was able to set it by running the following command: `npm set timeout 240000`

Comment: Its worth noting that that in addition to this, when running the 'npx create-react-app your-app' command again it appear to be intelligent enough to not redownload items it has so retrying the command may actually work too.

Comment: This is ridicolous. I have 30MBit/s and i hit this problem.

Comment: For mac, you can create `.npmrc` file by `sudo nano ~/.npmrc` then place "timeout=60000" inside the file.

Comment: Helped me on
Ubuntu 20.04
Node 18
npm 9

Answer (score 19):

I had a slow connection and I updated the timeout value to `.npmrc` using:

`npm set timeout=100000`

And to check if the value is updated (Mac): `vi ~/.npmrc`

Answer (score 9):

Users are extremely likely to face this issue if they are on a slow internet connection. To counter this, you need to increase the timeout in the npm's config file. And here's how to do it:

1. Find the `.npmrc` file (located in the nodejs installation folder; in my case, it's in `F:\Installations\nodejs\node_modules\npm` folder. But for you, it might be in `C:\program files` folder).
2. Open the `.npmrc` file and append this line: `timeout=240000` (usually it is 60 seconds I suppose, but since my connection was way slower therefore, I had to increase it to 240 seconds or 4 minutes, you can keep it 120000 for 120seconds)
3. Save the file

Since create-react-app fails midway, it can easily break npm's package.json file thus leading to this sort of issue:

`Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near`

Therefore, before running the `npx create-react-app`, run the following command: `npm cache clean --force` as it cleans the cache and (i think) repairs the `package.json` file.

Comment: i don't have an slow connection and i'm facing the same issue

Comment: It is most likely an npm bug, not a connection problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue. I Solved it like this:
create a new file with no name just an extinction of .npmrc
open this file in any editor and type timeout = 90000
save the file and in you terminal type

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app ./
```

Note: this error occurs because of slow internet speed

Comment: Creating a local `.npmrc` solved the issue for me.. didn't need the commands.

Comment: Thank you. This system works for me though my Internet Information Services option is unchecked

Answer (score 4):

I enabled IIS and the issue was solved for me:

1. do to Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features
2. click on Turn Windows features on and off
3. make sure the Internet Information Services is checked
4. click OK and wait for some minutes

Comment: Great answer. I had this problem for a while now and it turns out this was likely the root cause.  For just cmd solution use this - `Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /All`

Comment: thank you sooo much... that solved my issue. I had this issue with ionic and angular app and this really solved it after two days of research...

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs due to slow internet connection. Try installing when you get a better speed. If better speed doesn't solve your problem try this.

```
 npm cache verify
 npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: This saves my day! thanks

Answer (score 3):

**I was facing the same issue when create a react-app using** npx create-react app . And i fixed my problem by running the following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**I hope you find this helpful**

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem by setting timeout in user local `.npmrc` file to

```
timeout=600000
```

90000 is not enough for downloading many packages for projects with lot dependencies in `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything including factory resetting my Mac. Then after reinstalling everything and still having the same issue, I typed into the terminal and ran:

```
npm set timeout=100000
```

then sat my computer next to my router and ran npx create-react-app again and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered this error today while installing Firebase but [this helped me.](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4553#issuecomment-1196453677)

This is what I did:

```
npm config set fetch-retries 5
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 600000
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 1200000
npm config set fetch-timeout 1800000
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by running:

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org" --global
```

It appears the problem is related to the following post:

[npm install gets stuck at fetchMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433130/npm-install-gets-stuck-at-fetchmetadata)

And @CptUnlucky's solution worked for me on macOS Catalina 10.15.7, node v16.0.0, npm v7.12.2, nvm v0.38.0

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still running into this issue below with the error:

> Invalid response body while trying to fetch
> https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-config-react-app: Socket timeout

Run this script: **npm install react --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org**

and then **npx create-react-app mypp**

for your react app installation. Happy coding

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This Will fix your issue:**

```
npm config set fetch-retries 5
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 600000
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 1200000
npm config set fetch-timeout 1800000
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I solved it by enabling the Internet Information service (IIS) feature of the window.
Enabling the IIS
Steps:

1. Windown + r
2. Type appwiz.cpl and click OK
3. click on Turn window features on or off (on the Left top side)
4. wait some seconds and check the Internet information service option
5. Now wait until window apply changes.
6. create project again.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I tried all solutions over StackOverflow or Github discussions but nothing worked.
I changed the `.npmrc` file under the Users folder in C in Windows and changed the timeout from 30000 to 90000. See if 60000 works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the issue related to npm verison 6.14* 
Downgrading to npm verison 6.13.7 solved for me

```
npm i -g npm@6.13.7
```

It's also an newly opened issue
you can check more details about it at
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1185

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `npm i npm@6.13.7`   or `npm I -g npm@6.13.7` if you wanna this to be global version.

After that, just to make sure, run " npm -version " to see what version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to npm version 6.13.7 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

And remove your `node_modules` within your user.
In Windows, it is

```
C:\Users\${select_your_user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when running `npm install` on Docker.
I had to pass the HTTP and HTTPS proxy values to the image while building it.

`docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://<your_company_proxy> --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://<your_company_proxy>`

It worked fine after I passed these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the issue related to npm verison 6.14*
Downgrading to npm verison 6.13.7 solved for me

npm i -g npm@6.13.7
It's also an newly opened issue you can check more details about it at https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1185
it is works for me

Answer (score 0):

Editing the .npmrc file to 80000 works. If not, globally uninstall create-react-app:

```
"npm uninstall -g create-react-app" then run "npx create-react-app ./"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently have the same issue and following steps would help you.

1. npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org" --global (sets registry) (Try Again)
2. Go to you user folder find .npmrc file there and remove content of it.
3. run npm cache clean --force
4. still errors - Remove the content of npm base folder usually inside User/AppData/roaming/npm/...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it won't work if you use only letters in your app name e.g first I have used "myapp" and that was not working though I have done all the other stuffs correctly like set timeout = 240000 in .npmrc file and run the following commands

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app myapp
```

but that not working for me then I have just changed my project name from myapp -> my-app and it worked perfectly. So, If you are facing the same issue try them out. Hopefully, it saves your time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things for 3 days, then i figure out that new versions of nodejs doesn't work so fine for some computers, i downgrade to 16.0.0 and then worked

Answer (score 0):

First step 1) Remove package-lock.json , yarn.lock, node_modules

next step 2) then write this command in terminal  npm install -f

Answer (score 0):

**This is because of the network
Try to run again the command with good internet.**

or if you done that not not working then
delete node_modules and package.lock
clear the cache
and again run npm install
If this work for you then follow me.

Answer (score -2):

Regarding npx ...

If you have create-react-app  (CRA) globally installed;

it is recommend you uninstall CRA

to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

When using npx,  the global installation isn't used.

But it may interfere (addressed below).

---

Don't run your React app from your desktop.

Some operating systems may throw an error.

---

Windows OS users ...

As administrator (for steps #1 & #2),  inside your command-line ...

---

## 1)  uninstall your global version of  CRA.

npm uninstall -g create-react-app    Mac prefix: sudo

---

## 2)  Then ...

Run: npx create-react-app my-app    Mac prefix: sudo

Above:  This will create the latest version of

a React app named:  my-app.

This app will be created wherever your command-line is pointing.

---

## 3)  Open Google Chrome.

---

## 4)  cd my-app (point your command-line to your project folder).

---

## 5)  inside your command-line ... Run:  npm start