# docker with react connectivity issue

Tags: reactjs, docker

**my Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

**my docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  react-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3007:3000
    volumes:
      - /usr/app/node_modules
      - .:/usr/app
```

everytime i run docker-compose up, i get the following error

```
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/tsutils: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
```

OR

```
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/cross-spawn: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
```

tried the following -

1. [set timeout=6000000 in my .npmrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61378672/npm-err-response-timeout-while-trying-to-fetch-https-registry-npmjs-org-react)
2. [edited /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/957#issuecomment-627166787)
3. [changed /etc/docker/daemon.json](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32106#issuecomment-382228854)

my internet is fine

everytime i get the same error with a different package

what should i do ?