# Error occurs when running npm install after creating VueJS project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I just installed VueJS and I tried creating a project. I followed their installation and quick start guide [VueJS Getting Started.](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html)

`> npm init vue@latest`

`> cd (My Project Name Here)`

`> npm install`

However, after doing `> npm install`, it returns the following message in the VSCode Terminal:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alscg\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-07T08_54_47_537Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I fix this? Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this link it looks like it is answered already

[npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react-is (over 30000ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61378672/npm-err-response-timeout-while-trying-to-fetch-https-registry-npmjs-org-react)