# react app is not getting created using command npx create-react-react

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install, npx

I want to create react app but my npx create-react-app myapp command is  not working
D:\AED>npx create-react-app aed
npx: installed 98 in 52.503s

Creating a new React app in D:\AED\aed.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

it is stuck here for past 2 hours now .

Comment: Have you tried installing create-react-app globally first and then running it? `npm install -g create-react-app`. you **SHOULD** uninstall it globally after you have tried this tho, as stated on: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/ . We are just doing this as a test.

Comment: No will try this thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

`npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"`

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914481/3317728)