# npx stuck at fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

While running npx create-react-app command the process got stuck at **fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule create-react-app@4.0.3 checking installable status**. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Additional information such as other dependencies, network situation, etc—maybe even a sample repo—might lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

`npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"`

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914481/3317728)

Answer (score -2):

You will have to do this:
**npm install --global yarn**

Comment: Why `npm install --global yarn`? If this works, why? Are you sure it's not a network connectivity issue such as proxies? And what if the OP isn't using yarn?