# npm/yarn timeout with package on git:// url

Tags: linux, yarnpkg

My Angular app wont build.  It used to.
My workstation was updated to Pop OS 22.04. Another machine on Pop OS 21.10 is ok.
Im getting the following error from npm:

```
6284 verbose node v14.19.3
6285 verbose npm  v6.14.17
6286 error Error while executing:
6286 error /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/timaschew/cogent.git
6286 error
6286 error fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
6286 error github.com[0: 52.64.108.95]: errno=Connection timed out
6286 error
6286 error
6286 error exited with error code: 128
```

This log is from my build agent running on my workstation.

Using yarn directly I get a similar response:

```
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/timaschew/cogent
Directory: /mnt/win/dev/xxx/src/xxx.Client
Output:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 52.64.108.95]: errno=Connection timed out
```

I cant run that git ls-remote command directly either but if I switch it to https it works ok.  This is the only component in my package.lock file using git://

Comment: I think, this might be helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/189070/what-firewall-ports-need-to-be-open-to-allow-access-to-external-git-repositories

Comment: Thanks @user973254 but no luck with that

Comment: could you check if `git://` protocol connection unavailable only to github.com or any other host too?

Comment: Answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that/29411842

Answer (score 0):

For those currently experiencing the same error, please try this:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

And if you are working with some sort of CI/CD pipeline, it might be necessary to make the change manually in the `package-lock.json` file.

Ref: [This page](https://coderwall.com/p/sitezg/force-git-to-clone-with-https-instead-of-git-urls)