# git submodule update --init --recursive is not working

Tags: git

I am trying to cloning ardupilot git.

I tried to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` on Ubuntu 20.04 and get this error each time:

```
Cloning into '/home/asma/ardupilot/modules/libcanard'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Connection refused

fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/ArduPilot/libcanard.git' into submodule path '/home/asma/ardupilot/modules/libcanard' failed
Failed to clone 'modules/libcanard'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/asma/ardupilot/modules/libcanard'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Connection refused

fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/ArduPilot/libcanard.git' into submodule path '/home/asma/ardupilot/modules/libcanard' failed
Failed to clone 'modules/libcanard' a second time, aborting
```

Comment: `git://` protocol was disabled at Github in 2021. Switch submodule URLs to `https://` or `ssh://`. Use URL rewriting; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729634/7976758